# Jquery parse HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table id="tableData" name="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="XXX">10</a></td>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="YYY">4</a></td>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="XXX">7</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the td value which has hyperlink with class name in an array

The following code is not working

```
var rows = [];
$("#tableData tr").each(function() {
    $tr = $(this);
    var row = [];
    $tr.find(".tdvalue").each(function(){
        row.push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

This gives the value of the text with in the td.
but I need to class name of XXX `<a class="XXX">10</a>`

result would be:

```
Array[3] 0:"XXX" 1:"YYY" 2:"XXX"
```

Please help anyone

Comment: .attr('class') instead of .text()

Comment: to get the href it's pretty simple in the each function do $(this).find("a").attr("class")

Comment: thinks, forgot about .attr('class')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target the a's directly:

```
var row = [];

$(".tdvalue a").each(function() {
      row.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });

//gives row= ["XXX","YYY","XXX"]
```

```js
var row = [];
    
$(".tdvalue a").each(function() {
      row.push($(this).attr('class'));
   });

console.log(row)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" name="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="XXX">10</a></td>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="YYY">4</a></td>
        <td class="tdvalue"><a class="XXX">7</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```